# How hard would it be for Microsoft to support deployment of .net apps onto OSX and linux

Tags: linux, microsoft, apple, frameworks

Given the announcement of the windows 8 tablet edition and more details on the app store, it would be amazing if this infrastructure could be leveraged for the OSX desktop and or MonoTouch. http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2011/09/windows-8-experience/

Technically how hard would it be for Microsoft to do this?

Is the only problem strategic?

I know all about Mono, this is a question about microsoft supporting it directly from Visual Studio.

Comment: All of .NET? There are some parts of the BCL that are windows specific (WMI for instance).

Comment: Hi Chris, speculation about industry moves isn't on-topic here: we're not a discussion board. Check out [our FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) for more information about what's on-topic here.

Comment: Fair enough, no problem!

Answer (score 2):

Officially supporting .NET for other platforms would be a serious nail in Microsoft's coffin.

One of the reasons Windows succeeded where other operating systems failed has been due to Microsoft's support for the developer - Microsoft produce some of the best tools in the industry. Use of these tools however, come at a cost - you are tied to Windows. This suits microsoft greatly, as it boosts sales in Windows, and as such tools such as Visual Studio and .NET can be produced as loss leaders in order to tie users in to the Windows platform.

If Microsoft were to release .NET for Linux/Mac, then they will turn operating systems into a commodity - everyone could freely switch between operating systems and still have access to the same software (assuming everything was written in .NET).

Why would someone choose to buy Windows for £100+ when they can use Linux for free, and still get access to the same software?

There is just no incentive for Microsoft to do so, in fact it would be counter productive to their business.

Comment: Oh man, this post is just... ROFL. The only good developer tool that came out of Microsoft was Visual Studio (just the editor part). And even that was a joke until recently (a reason why companies like Whole Tomato exist).

Comment: @Let_Me_Be I'd argue that MOST tools offered from everyone were fairly incomplete until recently. Today, I'd be hard pressed to find an editor I like more than visual studio. SSMS is also fantastic, IMO.

Comment: Now, 3 years later, that Microsoft has open-sourced the .NET code, I'm not sure if this answer still applies.

Answer (score 0):

Well, they could talk nicely to Embarcadero & buy [Delphi](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi). There used to be a Linux version & the latest version is cross-platform Win/Mac/iOS.

The problem is soluble, it's just that the Linux & MacOS communities would represent around 20% of the desktop but 99% of the complaints.  The FLOSS brigade would expect MS to open source Visual Studio & the Cult of Steve would complain about the user experience.

That's without getting into any strategic stuff like why would MS want to encourage the uptake of other operating systems by providing an easy tool for migration.  If you could simply push a button & deploy to Linux or MacOS, the next audit MS did of a Government department would be its' last.